# Erro gráfico e lista simples

Tags: python, gráfico, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[]
y=[]
z=[]
dados=open('dados1.txt','r')
for line in dados:
    line=line.strip()
    X,Y,Z=line.split()
    x.append(X)
    y.append(Y)
    z.append(Z)
dados.close()
plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.plot(x,z,'o')
plt.show()
```

Fiz um programa que coleta dados de um arquivo txt e gera um gráfico, mas ao gerar o eixo y ficou estranho.

[image: Eixo y está estranho]

Comment: Qual o erro? Qual o comportamento desejado?

Comment: Olá, fica muito mais fácil de resolver o seu problema se você nos dizer qual é o seu problema (creio que seja a ordenação dos números no eixo y, mas deixe claro que este e o problema). Além disso, como não temos os seu dados, fica dificil reproduzir este problema. Seria muito bom ter um [mcve] para quer for responder reproduzir o seu problema.